# iterate using multi dimensional np.array

Tags: python, arrays, differential-equations

I've developed a class in order to solve backward euler using Newton-rapson method to solve the non linear equation. 
the class is suitable for the system of ODE as well (it takes an array of function ..)

this is my class:

```
class Backward(Euler):

    solved = False
    def __init__(self, dydt: Rhs, filename : str=' ', save :bool=True):

       self.save   = save
       self.file   = filename
       super().__init__(dydt)

    def solve(self):

        toll = 10e-12 
        self.time, self.u = self.dydt.createArray()   

        print('Running Newton-Rapson Backward Euler ....')

        for i in range(len(self.time)-1):
          u0 = self.u[i].T 
          u1 = u0 - np.linalg.inv(np.eye(len(self.dydt.u0)) - self.dt * self.dydt.Df(self.time[i+1],u0)) * (u0 - self.dt * self.dydt.f(self.time[i+1], u0).T - self.u[i].T )

          error = np.array([1.0])
          iters = 0
          while True:
              try:  
                 u0 = u1.T
                 u1 = u0 - np.linalg.inv(np.eye(len(self.dydt.u0)) - self.dt * self.dydt.Df(self.time[i+1],u0)) * (u0 - self.dt * self.dydt.f(self.time[i+1], u0).T - self.u[i].T )
                 iters += 1

                 error = np.abs(u1-u0)
                 if error <= toll:
                     break
                 if iters >= 10000:
                    raise ValueError('Too many iterations!') 
              except ValueError as ex:
                 print('Error occurred in Implicit-NR Euler Solvers: %s' %ex.args)
                 return None , None
          self.u[i+1] = u1.T
#-------------------------------------------      
        print('...Done!')
```

I got this error :

```
Running Newton-Rapson Backward Euler ....
Error occurred in Implicit-NR Euler Solvers: The truth value of an ars ambiguous.    
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If I try to use error.all() or error.any() the problem never converged ... 
the input parameters for this method is :

```
eq1 = lambda t,u : u[1]
eq2 = lambda t,u : u[2]
eq3 = lambda t,u : u[3]
eq4 = lambda t,u : -8*u[0]+ np.sin(t)*u[1]-3*u[3]+t**2


func1 = np.array([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4])
y0      = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4])
system1 = rhs.Rhs(func1, 0,5,y0, 1000 )
```

where Rhs is a wrapper class containing the data like function to be solved etc..

**EDIT** I follow your advise thanks .. I put `toll = 10e-3` but the problem doesn't solve... (Too many iteration) and also if i put error[0][0] printing it's `shape is 4,4` then i get

```
File "system01.py", line 41, in main
    bet,beu  = bwdeuler.solve()
  File "/home/marco/Programming/Python/Numeric/OdeSystem/euler.py", line 378, in solve
    self.u[i+1] = u1.T
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,4) into shape (4)
```

Comment: The `toll` value looks too small. Can you confirm whether this is the value you want? Increasing it will help you get to convergence faster. Also, error is an array. You can use something like `np.sum(np.abs(error)) <= toll` which is more intuitive and restrictive than `np.all`. Don't use `np.any` as it will give you a wrong answer.